# Do While Loop with Cell Offset Addition

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling with a Do While Loop. After trying several approaches, I now get an invalid qualifier error.

The goal of the code in the block is to find the minimum value of the range E3:E15, then add 1 to the cell to the right of it in the F3:F15 range.

The exit condition (Cell F2) is a sumproduct of F3:F15 and C3:C15. Once F2 meets or exceeds cell G2, a static target value, the goal has been met.

```
Dim MinRange As Range
Dim targetcell As String
Set MinRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E3:E15")
Do While Range("F2").Value < Range("G2").Value
    targetcell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(MinRange).Offset(0, 1).Address
    Range(targetcell) = Range(targetcell).Value + 1
Loop
```

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Min` returns a number, not a `Range`, so you can't use `Offset` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Match to locate the minimum value and offset from that:

```
Dim MinRange As Range, m

Set MinRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E3:E15")

Do While Range("F2").Value < Range("G2").Value
    m = Application.Match(Application.Min(MinRange), MinRange, 0)
    With MinRange.Cells(m).Offset(0, 1)
        .Value = .Value + 1
    End with
Loop
```